# Trait error in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, traits

I need to use Traits in symfony2. Different repositories extending different parents still use some common methods. I have created a trait that will contain those common methods. Unfortunately, when I call the action, Symfony2 throws an error saying :

```
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'Trait' (T_TRAIT), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
in src/AppBundle/Entity/Repository/CategoryRepository.php line 14
```

Here is one of the repositories

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository;
use AppBundle\Trait\HasDomainRepositoryTrait;
/**
 * CategoryRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class CategoryRepository extends NestedTreeRepository
{
    use HasDomainRepositoryTrait;

    public function search($domain, $onlyActive, $searchString = null)
    {
        $builder = $this->createBaseQuery($domain, $onlyActive);

        if ($searchString) {
            $builder
                    ->andWhere('e.name LIKE :searchString')
                    ->setParameter('searchString', '%'.strtolower($searchString).'%')
                    ;
        }

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

And here is the Trait :

```
namespace AppBundle\Trait;

trait HasDomainRepositoryTrait
{
    public function createBaseQuery($domain, $onlyActive = false)
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

        if ($domain) {
            $builder
                    ->andWhere('e.domain = :domain')
                    ->setParameter('domain', $domain)
                    ;
        }

        if ($onlyActive) {
            $qb->andWhere(sprintf('e.enabled = %s', $onlyActive));
        }

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

I'm using PHP 5.6 and Traits work (I've run a little simple test outside the project).
I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: You may not be able to make your namespace "Trait". Try changing the namespace to something else.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may not be able to make your namespace "Trait". Try changing the namespace to something else.

Comment: Shame that this is the case. It worked but seems very silly to me and I have no idea why this limitation exists.

Comment: @Ryall I think the same. I used the namespace `Mixin`, however my traits are named like: `ChosenNameTrait` which one did you choose?

Comment: Changed namespace "Trait" to "Traits" and all work